# Switch images dynamically (with PHP) but also with CSS media queries?

Tags: php, javascript, css, less

I have an image that replaces an  tag

```
<h1 id=myImage>Text</h1>
```

The css looks something like:

```
  h1#myImage {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background: url('myImage.jpg') no-repeat;
    width: 400px;
    height: 80px;
    }

    @media-only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    h1#myImage {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background: url('myImage-mobile.jpg') no-repeat;
    width: 400px;
    height: 80px;
    }
 }
```

This works the way I want it to (i.e. when I resize the browser, I see the mobile version of the image)...however now I need h1#myImage to change dynamically with a user's preference...so that "myImage.jpg" and "myImage-mobile.jpg" get swapped out with "myNewImage.jpg" and "myNewImage-mobile.jpg"

I'm also using LESS.js so maybe if there's some way to combine my CSS variables with php variables..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to convert your less file into a php file and do whatever you want variable wise in there then use that as the href in your link tag.

style.php

```
h1#myImage {
text-indent: -9999px;
background: url('<?php echo $image_name; ?>') no-repeat;
width: 400px;
height: 80px;
}
```

From

`<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less">`

To

`<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.php">`

This is what you would do in PHP for dynamic CSS before things like LESS were around.

Comment: @redconservatory The only performance hit would depend on how heavy of PHP processing you are doing before sending over the LESS file. On the client side there should be no difference.

Comment: There's always a small bit of perf hit when you process .less files on client side with less.js. Note that it's also depending on JS support (obviously, but this is with regards of your audience).